# I have to expand $\exp[-(x-t)]$ as product of series of $f(x)$ and $f(t)$, where $f(x)$ and $f(t)$ are polynomials.

Tags: exponential-function

I am trying to solve homogenous fredholm equation of second kind. The kernel is given by
$\exp[-(x-t) ]$. I have to separate the kernel as product of two function $f(x)$ and $f(t)$.

Comment: You may want to share some background of your question. How it arised, your attempts to solve it, things like this can others provide better insights to you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$e^{-(x - t)} = e^{-x} e^{t}$

Using the Taylor series formulas, we can expand as:

$e^{-(x - t)} = \left( 1 - x + {x^2 \over 2!} - {x^3 \over 3!} + \cdots \right) 
\left( 1 + t + {t^2 \over 2!} + {t^3 \over 3!} + \cdots \right)$